# Funktion von "nichts"

Tags: pronoun, capitalization

"Ich hole Geld" vs. "Ich hole nichts".

Warum schreibt man "nichts" nicht groß. Ich könnte jetzt meine Gedanken dazu aufschreiben, aber das spare ich mir lieber.

Comment: Weil es sich hier um das Indefinitpronomen "nichts" und nicht um das Substantiv "Nichts" handelt.

Comment: Aber warum? Die "Funktion" im Satz ist doch identisch, oder nicht?

Comment: Weder die Funktion noch die Bedeutung von "das Nichts" und "nichts" ist identisch. Möglicherweise solltest Du Dich erstmal über die Bedeutung informieren?

Comment: Die Funktion von "Geld" und "nichts". Ich hole etwas. Einmal ist das etwas "nichts" und einmal ist das etwas "Geld. Wo ist da jetzt der Unterschied?

Comment: Andersherum: woher sollte ich wissen, dass es nicht groß geschrieben wird? Das ist ja genau meine Frage. Auswendiglernen wird ja wohl kaum die Antwort sein? EDIT: I see, "es" ist ein Indefinitpronomen und damit ein "Platzhalter" und wird deswegen icht großgreschrieben. "Nichts" ist in dem Fall auch ein Indefinitpronomen; warum "nichts" allerdings ein "Indefinitpronomen" ist erschließt sich mir dann nicht ganz.

Comment: Setze einfach einen Artikel ein. "Ich hole das Nichts" hat eine andere Bedeutung als "Ich hole nichts". Würdest Du das Pronomen "etwas" groß schreiben? Nein? Die Groß/kleinschreibung in "Ich hole nichts." folgt derselben Regel wie in "Ich hole etwas."

Comment: Du solltest deine Gedanken zu einer Frage IMMER aufschreiben. Das hilft anderen, deine Frage besser zu verstehen und sie zu beantworten.

Comment: Nichts ist ein Platzhalter für das Gegenteil von allem oder Ähnlichem ...

Comment: @SebastianE: Doch. Etwas ist ein Platzhalter für das Gegenteil von allem, nämlich nichts. :)

Comment: Nichts ist Nichts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Nichts" ist hier ein Pronomen, das heißt, es steht zwar *für* (pro) etwas, was ein Substantiv (Nomen) wäre, ist aber keins. Es kann wie ein Substantiv ein Subjekt oder Objekt in einem Satz sein.

Pronomen werden grundsätzlich klein geschrieben (außer natürlich am Satzanfang).

Sätze mit *Pronomen*:

> *Ich* sage *nichts*.
> *Ich* sage *etwas*.
> *Er* sagte *viel* und *wenig* zugleich.
> *Ich* danke *ihr*.
> *Sie* dankt *mir*.
> *Das* ist *sein* Auto. (wie: des Besitzers Auto, Ottos Auto)
> *Jenes* ist *ihr solches*.

Wie in den Kommentaren zur Frage und zu dieser Antwort erwähnt, gibt es auch ein Substantiv ["das Nichts"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Nichts), das mehrere verschiedene, aber durchweg andere Bedeutungen hat als das Pronomen "nichts".

> Der Boden gab nach und Lara Croft fiel ins Nichts.
> Wie aus dem Nichts stand plötzlich ein Wolf vor ihr.
> Der neu errichtete Croft-Landsitz symbolisierte für Lara den Sieg des Seins über das Nichts.
> Zur Filmpremiere trug der Star ein Nichts von einem Kleid.

Comment: und des isso weil du des sahst, oder hast du weiterführende Belege? Bemerke, ein Beleg der weiterführt dürfte nicht ebenfalls bloße Behauptungen aufstellen, sonst wäre der ebenso nichtig.

Comment: Wie gesagt (und offenbar von jemandem gelöscht): ich werde hier keine Belege für simple Grundlagen der Sprache raussuchen, die man in jeder Anfängergrammatik nachlesen kann. Wenn du meinst, dass diese Frage auf einem höheren linguistischen Niveau  beantwortet werden müsste (Warum ist *nichts* ein Pronomen? o.ä.), gern, dann schreib eben eine eigene Antwort.

Comment: Du verkennst die Frage. Ich weiß auch nicht, wie ich die Frage angemessen motivieren soll, denn meine schnippische Bemerkung zielte in erster Linie auf Einsicht in deinen Wissensstand ab. Mit einem Anfänger über die Grammatik zu diskiturieren wäre aber wohl doch verschwendung deiner und meiner Zeit, denn es wäre höchst unangemessen, dich um eine Erklärung zu bitten, zu der du nach drei Versuchen offenbar nicht in der Lage bist, zumindest nicht willens.

Comment: Ich begreife dennoch nicht, weshalb die Antwort akzeptiert wurde, die der Frage kaum etwas hinzufügt. Es ist ja nicht so, dass man es klein schreibt, weil es ein Pronomen ist, sondern weil es kein Nomen sollte. Das eine schließt das andere nicht aus, denn das Argument wäre im Grunde nicht *konstruktiv*. Es reicht auch nicht, dass ein Nomen mit unterschiedlicher Bedeutung bekannt ist. Immerhin gibt es Polyseme. Schließlich müsste man zugeben, oder ausschließen können, dass der Fall zumindest mehrdeutig sein könnte. Es ist auch nicht erwiesen, dass das höhere Mathematik erfordert. Nur etwas Mühe

Comment: "Nichts" als Platzhalter bzw. Pronomen ist wahrscheinlich an Eindeutigkeit kaum zu überbieten? Was das Nomen betrifft, finde ich es interessant von "verschiedenen" Bedeutungen zu sprechen. Ich verstehe auch nicht wieso das Pronomen "nichts", dass sich immer auf "das Nichts" bezieht (also rein logisch), eine andere Bedeutung haben soll als "das Nichts". Aber darum ging es in meiner Frage nicht primär :)